# When instantiating a method that returns a variable...?

Tags: java, variables, methods, instantiation

Basically, I want to make sure that I'm doing this right. I'm calling these methods in another class. The methods specify to return a variable, so when instantiating them, should I be placing null in the parenthesis? I just want to make sure I'm doing this right.

```
public class IntSLList {
protected static IntSLLNode head, tail;
public  void createInst(){
    new IntSLList().isEmpty();
    new IntSLList().addToHead(null);
    new IntSLList().addToTail(null,null);
    new IntSLList().deleteFromTail();
    new IntSLList().printAll();
    new IntSLList().isInList(null);
    new IntSLList().delete(null);

}



public IntSLList() {
    //code
}
public static boolean isEmpty() {
    //code    }
public static void addToHead(String AN) {
    //code
}
public static void addToTail(String AN, Double AB) {
    //code
}
public static String deleteFromHead() { // delete the head and return its info; 
    //code
}
public static String deleteFromTail() { // delete the tail and return its info;
    //code

}
public static void printAll() {
    //code    
}
public static boolean isInList(String AN) {
   //code
}
public static void delete(String AN){ 
//code
}}
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: What is `createInst()` supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure you want your fields and methods to be static? Also, default value will be null for head and tail.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You have a single constructor here. The rest are methods. And theey're static methods, so they should be called on the class: `IntSLList.isEmpty()` for example. What you pass as argument is what you want to pass as argument. If you want to pass null, you pass null. If you want to pass something else, you pass something else.

Comment: you don't 'instantiate' methods, you call them. why would you pass null as parameter, unless it takes an Object (of any type) as argument, and you have nothing to pass?

Comment: Yes, I want the methods to be static, the methods in the program that I'm calling these to are static. 

I don't want it to pass null, but I don't know what I should be putting there in place of null if I want it to pass the data that would be stored in its place.

Comment: @UberPwnd: that's not a good reason for a method to be static. A Java program always start by running the main method, which is static. By your reasoning, every method of every class would be static, since it's called from main, which is static. You really need to read a Java tutorial about objetcs, methods and constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate methods at all, they are already "prepared for use" when your list gets instantiated.

What you want to do is remove the `static` keyword from the methods: It means that the methods are defined "global" for the whole class instead of just for one specific list.

Update: This is the list class as I imagine it should be

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntSLList {
  protected int head,tail;
  //I'll use this as examplelist, so I can omit the list implementation
  private ArrayList<Integer> dataList;

  public IntSLList(){
    //Do initalization
    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addToHead(int node){
    dataList.add(0, node);
  }

  public void addToTail(int node){
    dataList.add(node);
  }

  public boolean isEmpty(){
    return dataList.isEmpty();
  }

  // ... snip other list methods here ...

}
```

You can use/access it like this:

```
public class ListMain {

public static void main(String[] args){
  IntSLList myList = new IntSLList();

  myList.addToHead(1);
  myList.addToTail(2);
  System.out.println("myList.isEmpty() = " + myList.isEmpty());
}

}
```

Comment: I can't call them when they are non-static from my other class though, as it is static... If I tried to take away the static out of public static void main(String[] args) it wouldn't run. Otherwise I would have made my first class non-static, it would have saved me a lot of headaches in the beginning...

Comment: The two fields `head` and `tail` need to be non-static as well, of course. Your static main() can stay that way, if you use the above code in your main, it should work as expected

Comment: @tannereil I see where your're coming from, but I had problems in my seperate main class in the methods where I'm calling the these methods to being non-static that I had to use a workaround for. When calling these I had to set these up as static in order to access them. :/

Comment: I updated my answer to make a more sophisticated example for you to copy/adapt into your code

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT!!! :D Silly me didn't do this in my Bank Class:

IntSLList list= new IntSLList(); 

And then call my functions with list.method();